# Drupal - Block body is not saved/shown

Tags: drupal

i added this in my Drupal theme:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<?php print $sidebar; ?>
</div>
```

Additionally I added this in the .info file:

```
regions[sidebar] = Sidebar
```

I then created a new block with "Add block" in the admin panel and assigned the created Block to the sidebar. Unfortunately everything i wrote in the block body is not saved and therefore the sidebar does not show any contents. If I update the block body and click on save and go into edit mode to have a look, the block body is empty.

Anybody knows why this happens and how i can solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you move the block into another region, is it visible?

Answer (score 0):

If this is in your `page.tpl.php`, you should be using `$page['sidebar']` rather than just `$sidebar`. You also have to call `render()` on the region. Lastly, it's a good idea to check if it's defined first. For instance:

```
<?php if($page['sidebar']): ?>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <?php print render($page['sidebar']) ?>
  </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Don't forget to clear the cache after adding a new region as well.

See the Bartik theme's `page.tpl.php` for a more complete example: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/bartik/tree/templates/page.tpl.php.